# How to call multiple API's asynchronously in Vue js

Tags: vue.js, promise, vuejs2

I have some functions that call API's in methods and want to execute them as a Promise.

```js
methods: {
      promise1() {
        alert("1");
      },
      promise2() {
        alert("2");
      },
      promise3() {
        alert("3");
      }
}
```

How can I do this?

Edit: Title changed to show I want to call API's asynchronously.

Comment: What do you mean by "*execute them as a Promise*"? There is nothing asynchronous in the code you posted, so there's zero reason to use promises.

Comment: @Bergi My purpose was to run functions respectively one by one and be sure that the next function runs when previous function finish. if there is better way to do this please tell me.

Comment: What do your functions do? Are they asynchronous?

Comment: All of them are not asynchronous. for example I want to call two apis and after that run a function. I think I could have chosen better ways for doing this. I could have pass the last function as a callback of the second function.

Comment: Then just write `method1(); method2(); method3();`. No asynchrony, no promises.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this and add it here :

```
methods: {
        promise1() {
          alert("1");
        },
        promise2() {
          alert("2");
        },
        promise3() {
          alert("3");
        }
    },
    mounted() {
      Promise.all([this.promise1(), this.promise2(), this.promise3()])
      .then(function() {
         alert("Finished");
      });
    }
```

In `mounted()` we can write a `promise.all()` and add functions in array.